# Need to swap 2 lines

Tags: regex, sed

For each instance of the below code (have many) I need to swap the "userId" line with the "screen_name" line so "screen_name" line is above "userId" line.

```
{
  active: true,
  userId: '14053424',
  screen_name: '0xstark',
  maxTopTweets: 2,
  minLikesCount: 2,
  keywordsToReject: [],
  keywords: [],
  useDefaultKeywords: true,
  useDefaultRejectKeywords: true,
  useStrictKeywords: false,
  defaultPhoto: null,
},
```

Comment: see the guidelines here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flip the lines of user_id and screen name:

```
awk '/userId:/{uid=$0;next}/screen_name/{$0 = $0 RS uid}1' input
```

This is storing the line containing  the string `userId:` into a variable `uid` and moving to next line , whenever it sees a string `screen_name` it will reconstruct that line like `$0 = $0 RS uid` where `RS` is used to get new line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you  (GNU sed):

```
sed '/userId:/{h;d};/screen_name:/G' file
```

Save the `userId` line in the hold space and append it to the `screen_name` line.

N.B. Assumes the `userId` always precedes the `screen_name` line.